# NodeJS: forward form-data to external API

Tags: node.js, multipartform-data

Looking for help to solve my issue, any advice appreciated!

So I'm uploading csv file as formdata to Node environment with XHR request:

```
       var FormData = new FormData();
    var file = input.files[0];
FormData .append("file", file);
```

In the Node environment I receive the following under req.files with JSON.stringify:
[image: req.files]

Next I need to add authorization header and send the same data to external API.

**What I have tried:**

- using request module and ```.pipe()``
- using busboy
- and axios with form-data
- basically all these posts: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53220350/how-to-forward-a-multipart-form-data-post-request-in-node-to-another-service), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13797670/nodejs-post-request-multipart-form-data), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52963648/how-to-pass-multipart-request-from-one-server-to-another-in-nodejs/53002980), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9327250/how-to-resend-post-multipart-form-data-form-with-upload-file-to-different-server), [5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46975590/how-to-upload-file-saved-in-memory-by-multer-to-another-api), [6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53590923/node-js-send-form-data-to-another-server), [7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51765755/sending-file-from-one-node-js-server-to-another)

But file is not being sent correctly and server responds with 400.

**Limitations** As this Node environment is cloud based I cannot access any of the config js files and therefore use express.

Thanks

Comment: It would be helpful to include the code of your attempts, e.g. with the `request`-module. Also are you able to perform the upload to the remote server using curl/postman?

Comment: @eol I though of adding code, but it would create hell of a long post, as I tried 10-15 different ways. I didn't use `fs createStream` as I do not have the path, though. But uploading file from postman works, also uploading directly from browser works, the problem is with forwarding only.

Comment: @Shanir Any luck on this? I m also facing the same

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve what you are looking for with `axios`

```js
const axios = require("axios")
const FormData = require("form-data")
const fs = require("fs")

const url = "your.url.com"
const form_data = new FormData()
form_data.append("file", fs.createReadStream(localPath))

const request_config = {
  headers: {
    ...form_data.getHeaders()
  },
  maxContentLength: Infinity,
  maxBodyLength: Infinity,
  auth: { // if auth is needed
    username: USERNAME,
    password: PASSWORD
  }
}

return axios.post(url, form_data, request_config)
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks @davidrv87 The problem with using `fs.createReadStream` is that I don't understand what to pass for the path of the file? I do not see any path in the request..

Comment: There is no need to pass a file. You can pass values - see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append